# Make android app not availble for tablets

Tags: android, tablet

I am publishing my app in the Play store and i don't want it to be available for tablets. 
How can i make it happen?

I don't want to manually exclude every single tablet within the developer console of android but i really need my application to run exclusively on smartphone.

EDIT:
I did as you suggested but here's the result:

[image]

And for further explanation: i need my app to run on devices that normal people call smartphone and not on devices that normal people call tablets... e.g. it has to run on "Galaxy Note 2" but not on "Galaxy Tab"

**SOLVED** Thanks to @CommonsWare:

I had to set the following tags in my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>
```

and:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

And do the following:
Right click on project -> properties -> android -> select a target greater than 8

Comment: why is that ? (also, please define 'tablet')

Comment: If the reason is that your application needs phone voice call access, please be aware that some tablets can support voice calls (e.g. I have a ViewSonic ViewPad 7" that is basically just an oversized phone).

Comment: If you did'nt want tablets to be included, i wonder why have you also written the <screenSize="large"> elements.?

Comment: Don't do it programmatically. Just exclude some devices in the Google Play Concole.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps

> ...you can use the  element to manage the distribution of your application based on combinations of screen size and density. External services such as Google Play use this information to apply filtering to your application, so that only devices that have a screen configuration with which you declare compatibility can download your application.

The sample `<compatible-screens>` element from that page:

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

However, I would recommend also adding lines for a density of `xxhdpi`, as such devices are shipping now (Droid DNA, Xperia Z, HTC Butterfly, etc.).

---

**UPDATE**

First, with respect to your build errors, if you read [the documentation for the `<compatible-screens>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html), you will notice that it was added in API Level 9, and for some strange reason, you build target is set older than that.

Second, with respect to:

> i need my app to run on devices that normal people call smartphone and not on devices that normal people call tablets... e.g. it has to run on "Galaxy Note 2" but not on "Galaxy Tab"

This is not possible, simply because you do not have a concrete definition of what you do and do not want your app shipping on.

There are ~8 billion "normal people" on the planet. You are welcome to interview each one of them and ask them what they think the Galaxy Note 2 is. Some will say a phone. Some will say a tablet. Some will say a "phablet", which will not be useful. Some will chase you out of their homes, claiming that you have brought some light-emitting demon into their midst (this too will not be useful, and may be painful if they have stones handy to throw).

If, at some point in time in the future, you come up with a scientific definition of what you do and do not want to ship your device on, ask a fresh StackOverflow question. By "scientific definition", I mean an algorithm that can be universally applied, by all people on all devices, to determine what you do and do not want your app on.

(note that by "all people", I am excluding those who might consider you to be a demon-monger)

For example:

- "I want to ship on all devices that have telephony capability, regardless of screen size"
- "I want to ship on all devices that have a screen size smaller than such-and-so many inches on its smallest side:

Comment: You are right (and made a very hilarious answer. Honest!). I need to ship on devices smaller than 6 inches. 
Now i have: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="9"/> But it is still giving me the same errors as in the image i posted!

Comment: @aveschini: You need to set your *build target* to API Level 9 or higher. In Eclipse, that is in Project > Properties > Android.

Comment: I only had to add the following:


        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

Comment: @CommonsWare It seems that a value of `xxhdpi` it is not allowed for `screenDensity`, even the `targetSdkVersion="19"` ... From what I found on SO, we have to use `480` It is correct?

Comment: @AlexAndro: You have to use `480` instead of `xxhdpi`.

Comment: Note that today, you need to also support xxhdpi and xxxhdpi and also resolutions in between. Because for older SDK version xxhdpi is not supported you should add those resolutions by number:
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
and the same for 560 and 640 as well as for screenSize="small".

Answer (score 7):

Use Support screen tag in manifest file is **wrong method**. Alway use `<compatible-screens>` to make your app not available to tablet.

```
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="false" />
```

**Caution**

> If you use the  element for the above scenario
>   (when your application is not compatible with larger screens) and set
>   the larger screen size attributes to "false", then external services
>   such as Google Play do not apply filtering. Your application will
>   still be available to larger screens, but when it runs, it will not
>   resize to fit the screen. Instead, the system will emulate a handset
>   screen size (about 320dp x 480dp; see Screen Compatibility Mode for
>   more information). If you want to prevent your application from being
>   downloaded on larger screens, use  as suggested by **@CommonsWare**.

Use  tag for exclude your app to run on tablet.

```
<compatible-screens>
<!-- all small size screens -->

  <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

  <!-- all normal size screens -->

  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: This will not work. Android will still ship the app to larger-screen devices and will apply its own algorithm to scale up the UI.

Comment: As stated in another Thread this solution depends on the definition of 'tablet', which might not be what aveschini wants.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: 'android:resizeable' This attribute is deprecated. from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Answer (score 2):

For those new to the thread, use

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" required="true"/>
```

Source (https://paramsen.github.io/exclude-tablets/)

Comment: But my tablet does make calls so this would not work for user case where developer doesnt want to deal with tablet layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update for 2023 with a few tweaks. At this moment in time there are a lot of foldable phones coming out and they're reporting as tablets. This is probably why they don't want to have a simple "exclude tablets" button on Play Console.

I was able to include these newer phones while still excluding tablets by making the assumption phones had higher pixel densities and tablets generally have lower pixel densities. This is true today but not guaranteed in the future so hopefully Google addresses this issue in a better way soon.

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="360" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="640" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="360" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
    <!-- phones only with large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />
```

Answer (score -3):

You might try adding a check of some sort for 3g or 4g service. That will exclude most, but probably not all tablets.

Comment: idk what should we do with this answer