# Android - incompatible device

Tags: android

A user tell me that he can't download app from Play Store because incompatible device. He has an Huawei Mate 8.

App is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alitalia.mobile&hl=it

Manifest has some limitation to exclude tablets:

```
<compatible-screens>

    <!-- normal -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="normal" />

    <!-- large -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="large" />


</compatible-screens>

 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="true" />
```

Can anyone suggest possible causes?

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15548054/3838663

Answer (score 0):

You are excluding xxhpdi and xxxhdpi screens by omitting them.
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer first. According to Google documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

do you think they miss xxhdpi and xxxhdpi for android:screenDensity ?

Comment: Here you can see the size you should exclude if you don't want tablets: https://developer.android.com/images/screens_support/screens-ranges.png
Keep in mind that density and size are not the same thing. To exclude tablets you have to omit size, but to support phones you should include all densities.

Answer (score 0):

chagne `android.hardware.telephony` to `required=false` (if app must not use that future) also remove all `<compatible-screens>` element if your app is not for specific device. re upload new APK and check supported device count.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I need to exclude all tablet. Do you have a better solution to do that?

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHandsetApps

Answer (score 0):

There is no distinction in Android for Tablet vs. Phone, so you can't effectively filter by screen dimension or resolution.

There are Tablets with super low screen resolution (think low end cheap Tablet) vs. and small phones with very high resolution (the newest Samsung Note for example).

It is difficult to filter your app for Tablets - you should either:

- Find a particular feature that you require that is only on phones (like telephony service)
- Ensure your app is responsive and works on all screen sizes

Bottom line, there is NO difference between phones and tablets in the Android world, and you will so there are more important nuances to consider when filtering apps.

*Re-think your requirement regarding filtering from tablets, and consider your goal in a different way.*