# App not compatible with 18 inch tablet because Manifest?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I have uploaded an app to the Google Play Store. It's available for tablets only.
This is in my manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

Someone with a Samsung Galaxy View SM-T670 is trying to download my application. This tablet is 18.4 inch but my app is not compatible with this device. Why is it not compatible?

I checked, the device has a camera, so that can't be the problem.

I can't think of anything else because it has everything my manifest wants, but when I look the device up in the Google Developer Console, it says:

> This device is not supported in your app's APK-manifest. Therefore, users of this model can not install your app.

Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT: the tablet has a higher SDK then the minimum required SDK.

I don't think it does matter which country the user comes from because when I look in the Google Developer Console, it also shows the message that the app is not compatible with that device. So my guess is that country doesn't matter?

Comment: What country is the user in? Is the application available in that country? Is the tablet running a newer version than your app minSdkVersion ?

Comment: I edited the question, not only the users says it is not compatible but the Google Dev Console also shows the message for that device. And yes the tablet is running a newer version. @RobertEstivill

Comment: Probably the dpi of the tablet is too low as you specified `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"`. Tablets are annoying stuffs because they have big screen and sh*tty resolution.

Comment: Is it possible that such a huge tablet has not 600dp? @Eselfar

Comment: Yup. If the resolution is 1920x1080 you end with something like 122.38dpi. I hate working with tablets for this reason. Check the screen specifications to be sure.

Comment: have you find your solution?

Comment: I did not have any time to test it yet.. But I think @Eselfar is right. I'm going to test that later this week.

Comment: Have you tried `<compatible-screens>` instead of `<supports-screens>`? I haven't tested myself. More info https://stackoverflow.com/a/15548054/1827254  |  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html  |  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: @Eselfar you should answer the question because you commented the right thing twice. It does work now, I removed the line: android:requiresSmallesWidthDp and I added supports screens! Thanks

Comment: @476rick Hi! I'm happy that it solves your issue. I've added my answer.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"` which means you expect the screen to be at least 600dpi. But tablets have a very big screen and bad resolution (generally up to 1920x1080) so you end with something like 122 dpi for a 18 inches tablet. It means most of the tablets will be excluded which is the opposite of what you try to achieve.
So first remove this line.

Then you're using `<supports-screens>` which:

> Lets you specify the screen sizes your application supports and enable screen compatibility mode for screens larger than what your application supports.

(See [developer page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html))

In your case I think it's better to use `<compatible-screens>`. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) it

> Specifies each screen configuration with which the application is compatible.

It not advised to used it generally because:

> This element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your application, by not allowing users to install your application if they have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed.

Which is exactly what you want to do. See more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15548054/1827254).