# Restrict application to be installed on Mobile devices only and exclude Tablets

Tags: android, mobile

I'm creating an application which needs to be installed on mobile devices only and all the tablets should be excluded. There are already many same questions asked but at that time xxxhdpi resolution devices where not launched like Pixel 2 and Samsung Galaxy S8 plus which comes uder large screens. So how to restrict the apps to be installed on mobile devices only?

I tried below code but its not helping.

```
<compatible-screens>

        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />

    </compatible-screens>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make android app not availble for tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547985/make-android-app-not-availble-for-tablets)

Comment: where to restrict? on `play store`? if so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429070/android-disable-to-install-app-on-tablets

Comment: Yes only mobile devices can install the app @Bek

Comment: @Prem that answer does not provide me solution for xxxhdpi devices and tablets.

Comment: as @shah has stated that solution will exclude devices with high resolutions. What you can do is add the telephone hardware as a requirement as "some" tablets lack the feature.

Comment: @NizaSiwale Yes but that will exclude only some tablets..not all :-)

Comment: @rahulshah The other work around "could" have been listing some screen aspect ratios as incompatible but as of 2017 there is no way of doing that. You can only do that at run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anybody who's facing same issue can try this below code.

```
<compatible-screens>

    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />


    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Screen density 640 is the highest density for Phone devices. I've checked it on playstore it will exclude all tablets and will include all devices.